# How to optimize this pythagoras triples implementation

Tags: haskell, optimization, allocation

Here's haskell code

```
import GHC.Int

triples = [(x, y, z) | z <- [(1::Int32)..],
                       x <- [(1::Int32) .. z + 1],
                       y <- [x.. z + 1],
                       x * x + y * y == z * z]

main = mapM_ print (Prelude.take 1000 triples)
```

Which has following profile

```
       triples +RTS -p -RTS

    total time  =       47.10 secs   (47103 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc = 62,117,115,176 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE MODULE    SRC                      %time %alloc

triples     Main      triples.hs:(5,1)-(8,46)  100.0  100.0

                                                                              individual      inherited
COST CENTRE  MODULE                SRC                     no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN         MAIN                  <built-in>              118          0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 CAF         Main                  <entire-module>         235          0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
  main       Main                  triples.hs:10:1-46      236          1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  triples    Main                  triples.hs:(5,1)-(8,46) 237          1  100.0  100.0   100.0  100.0
 CAF         GHC.Conc.Signal       <entire-module>         227          0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF         GHC.IO.Encoding       <entire-module>         216          0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF         GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv <entire-module>         214          0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF         GHC.IO.Handle.FD      <entire-module>         206          0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF         GHC.IO.Handle.Text    <entire-module>         144          0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 main        Main                  triples.hs:10:1-46      238          0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
```

While equivalent `rust` code runs an order of magnitude faster. Which seems very strange to me.

```
fn triples() -> impl Iterator<Item=(i32, i32, i32)> {
    (1..).flat_map(|z| {
        (1..z + 1).flat_map(move |x| {
            (x..z + 1).filter_map(move |y| {
                if x * x + y * y == z * z {
                    Some((x, y, z))
                } else {
                    None
                }
            })
        })
    })
}

fn main() {
    for triple in triples().take(1000) {
        println!("{:?}", triple);
        // unsafe {printf("(%i, %i, %i)\n".as_ptr() as *const i8, x, y, z)};
    }
}
```

Results are

```
[I] ~/c/pythagoras (master|✚1…) $ time ./range > /dev/null
0.16user 0.00system 0:00.16elapsed 100%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2248maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+124minor)pagefaults 0swaps
[I] ~/c/pythagoras (master|✚1…) $ time ./triples > /dev/null
2.39user 0.00system 0:02.39elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 4736maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+473minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Both results are with `-O3` flag.

Is it possible to optimize allocations out while saving idiomatic haskell code? Maybe some fusion library or something can do this?

EDIT1. Okay using `Int` instead of `Int32` or `Int64` makes the code faster which is nice. Still with `fflvm` it's twice slower than rust and judging by profile it's still spends most of the time in allocations. What's preventing haskell from reusing the triple for example and not allocating it only once?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info

Comment: Your third generator should be starting from x+1, I think? In a Pythagorean triple, x and y should always be different numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. For performance, you should compile *without* profiling, and with optimization. Profiling adds significant overhead. On my system `ghc -prof` results in a runtime of over **40** seconds, similarly to your time. `ghc -O2` without `-prof` yields just **4.2** seconds.
2. Using `Int32` on a 64 bit system. You shouldn't do this, because non-native sized `Int` operations are compiled to slow out-of-line primops. When I change `Int32` to `Int`, runtime becomes **0.44** seconds. If I additionally use `-fllvm` for the LLVM code backend, I get **0.2** seconds.

Comment: Of course I'm compiling with `O3` It's in my post in the end. Okay, with `fllvm` and `Int` runtime is now `0.27s` against `0.14` in rust. I have two question. Why using `Int64` isn't as fast as using `Int` on my `amd64` machine? Another question is why it's still twice as slow? I've read posts that compared rust to haskell and most of the time haskell had the same runtime. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps change your implementation?

```
triples = [(m^2-n^2,2*m*n,m^2+n^2) | m<-[2..], n<-[1..(m-1)]]
```

Comment: It is not clear to me that this generates the same list (up to ordering).  It seems to empirically but would like a reference at least (it's cool though!)

Comment: Here is one reference: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PythagoreanTriple.html formula is perhaps older than two millennia.  With relative prime and different parity (odd, even) constraints on `n,m` you can get the primitive triples. The OP does generate the multiples of primitives as well, so I didn't bother.

Comment: The point is to use the same implementation for all languages and compare performance of it.